# Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string on mybb

Tags: php, mysqli

I did some searching and saw people talking about looping the results because they can't be directly accessed as text, but all I'm calling with this query is 1 piece of information.

***Here is the entire error screen that shows up......***

```
MyBB has experienced an internal error and cannot continue.
Error Type:
Catchable Fatal Error (4096)

Error Message:  Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string
Location:  File: inc/functions_online.php
```

Code:

```
    $queryz = $db->query("SELECT location FROM mybb_testing8 WHERE uid='1'");
    echo $queryz;
```

Backtrace:

```
File    Line    Function
/inc/class_error.php
    208
    errorHandler->output_error
/inc/functions_online.php
    1044
    errorHandler->error
/online.php
    242
    build_wol_row
```

***......end of error screen......***

I don't know if the "Backtrace" info above helps figuring this out or not.  The command I'm trying to get to work is shown in the error above.  **What I want is to view the piece of information that's in the "location" column for user 1 in the mybb_testing8 table.** How do I do that?  Can somebody help me understand why this is not working, in the simplest terms possible for somebody who is VERY new to this?  Also, can somebody convert the coding to a workable version?

Comment: this $queryz is object and u cant echo this at best print_r() to see whats in there !!

Comment: When I print it like that, it tells me this:  **ignormysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 1 [lengths] => [num_rows] => 1 [type] => 0 )**

...but what I want is to view the piece of information that's in the "location" column for user 1 in the mybb_testing8 table.  How do I do that?

Comment: yes its an object now u need to fetch the data to get the values @@ check in your DB class for related methods to do so.

Comment: I guess I just don't understand the terminology.  What do I physically do in order to "check in my DB class for related methods"?  Please explain more specifically as I am very new to PHP and SQL.  I have not had any schooling on this at all; my apologies.